# What is the "WebPlusDB.txt" file's purpose within the public_html directory when using Serif WebPlus?

Tags: public-html

I've been using Serif WebPlus X8 web design tool now for some years. I'm not expert by any stretch, but generally find my answers by trawling and digesting the evidence.

However- I am stuck on what is a `WebPlusDb.txt` file in the `/public_html/` directory, what it does or achieves?
How do you update it?

I ask because when I upload, and the manifest updating words show up it takes about 40 mins to do, and I suspect its due to this?

Comment: This is such a  speficic request for a niche product, I am voting to close.  However, have you tried contacting them? https://webplus.com.au/contact-us

Comment: thank you steve for your comment. Yes, and previous other forum entries have disappeared. There used to be a lively forum sharing ideas from which i remember their being an answer to this question, but no longer shows up. At the time, in 2018, my uploading 'manifest' check was almost instantaneous. The file and manifest may be two different aspects, but I dont know-hence the question.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the file?  It may give you some clues?

Comment: yes, it was written in a code I've never seen before, just a load of obscure shapes. Hence my question to find some enlightenment from a more learned resource. I didnt think it was such a niche product, being widely used by web authors, so considered that there would be a number of members able to post clarification.

Comment: For the benefit of those who may follow this thread, I beleive I have found the answer. The WebPlusDb.txt file records the changes made in one's updates to your website so the software can compare what needs to be changed/deleted as requested. This file though is accumulative and can get quite large. Its best if its renewed periodically by adding .old to the extg file and republishing the site, whereupon it self renews a much smaller file, resulting in a quicker sign-off of the upload. Hope that helps.